# movement inside an multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array that I am displaying with a table how can i use user input for movement
currently 0 is assigned to every array but I plan on assigning other values to the array:

my question is - how can i move up, down, right, left, and move diagonally within the array using user input

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 ) 
        [3] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 ) 
        [4] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 ) 
        [5] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 ) 
        [6] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 ) 
        [7] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 ) 

    ); 


                array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
```

It is for a checkers game no mysql.

I can already serialize the array into text file, but the text files needs to contain the start position and when each player makes a move put the location the piece move to in the text file then call back to the display

and I have already displayed the array into an html table

I am also trying to restrict movement to illegal square but that's a logic problem i need work on myself

will this loop work with code below

```
                $row = 0;
                print "<form>";
                print "<table border = 1>";
                while ($row < 8){ // Counts to 8. (from 0...7 = 8 times. 0 ... 8 = 9 times)
                   print "<tr>";
                   $row++;
                   $col = 0; // reset column to 0 each time printing one row.

                   while ($col < 8){
                    print "<td>";
                    if($board[$row][$col] == 0)
                    {

                    print "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"box[]\" value=\"$value\">";
                    // Add \ before " otherwise it will treat as the end of the quote.

                    }
                    print "</td>";
                    $col++;

                   }

                   print "</tr>";

                }
                print "</table>";
                print "</form>";
```

I already created a database for keeping score but that will be finished after this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the available movement for the game, in this case, from the players point of view you can say that a player can move it's piece:

1. up-left
2. up-right
3. up-left-up-left
4. up-right-up-right

Note that the two last elements of the list are those of one piece eating another one. Once you know that you can take the current position of the piece and move it to the new one. I'm going to assume that for normal pieces you would use "N" and for queens "Q" although I will not use queens in my examples. 
I will use a normal move and then an actual eating one:

```
//Piece at $board[$x][$y] moves diagonally to the left.
$board[$x-1][$y+1] = $board[$x][$y]; // This space is occupied
$board[$x][$y] = 0; //Now the space is empty
```

Now for the eating part. Lets imagine that the piece on `$board[$x][$y]` wants to eat the one that's in diagonally left.

```
//Eating action from $board[$x][$y]
$board[$x-1][$y+1] = 0; //It's been eaten!
$board[$x-2][$y+2] = $board[$x][$y]; // This space is occupied
```

So you could get an input from the user that included, the piece he wants to move, and what kind of movements he wants to do (I'm assuming, you will only allow the correct moves so I will not get into that). If you are reading it from a form submit for example you could get the movement, the position and the player (for orientation) as `$_POST` variables.

Then depending on those values modify the `$board` array. To do so, you could use conditionals or a switch, that's up to you.

```
$way = ($_POST['player'] === 'up')? 1:-1;
```

That last line will allow you to re-use the same code for the movements, multiplying the values you have to add to the current position to get to the new one, by the `$way` variable. For instance, going diagonally left would be:

```
//if player is 'up' then the value of $way is 1 so
$board[$x+(-1*$way)][$y+(1*$way)] = $board[$x][$y]; // position 2,2 becomes 1,3
//if player is not 'up' then the value of $way is -1 so
$board[$x+(-1*$way)][$y+(1*$way)] = $board[$x][$y]; // position 2,2 becomes 3,1
```

This should give you a starting point, all code was un-tested so I guess there may be some typos.

**UPDATE**

If all you want is to move from X,Y to X<sup>1</sup>Y<sup>1</sup> then:

```
$board[$var3][$var4] = $board[$var1][$var2];
$board[$var1][$var2] = 0;
```

Is about all you need. :)

Comment: I am doing 2 input boxes for "From" and another 2 input boxes for "to" ---> from ($var1,$var2) to ($var3,$var4) then request this information info the above solution you gave me

Comment: Thanks for the compliment Charlie

Comment: I don't think your effort is wasted

Comment: As long as you understand it a little bit better than before asking, it wasn't wasted. :)

Comment: well the first two code snippets i get. the last two code snippets it what i am having problem understanding.

Comment: @hgbso: Let me clarify. You could set different values for the same movements for each player. But they're essentially the opposite of each other, so we check which player is moving, and multiply by 1 (so it stays the same) or by -1 (so it's the opposite). Now?

Comment: so this is to see which player has a turn to move and in which way they can move

Comment: not exactly, the line `$way = ($_POST['player'] === 'up')? 1:-1;` checks the `$_POST['player']` value, which should come from your form, a field name 'player' with a value of 'up' for the one on the bottom, and 'down' for the one at the top. Then depending on that value it does what I explained on the previous comment.

Comment: oh ok so this check if one player is at one side of the table[bottom] and the other[top] one players move would go downwards and the other upwards

Comment: for the code before you added the update do i change the variables to accept user input like what you did with the update

Comment: can the code from the pre-update use user input to process movement

Answer (score 1):

You can access every field of the board using its coordinates:

```
$array[$y][$x]
```

So, if you want to move something up, you can simply do:

```
$array[$y-1][$x] = $array[$y][$x];
$array[$y][$x] = 0;
```

Comment: that's what i was thinking to but did not have clue to go about actually doing it

Comment: $array[$y][$x]
 this takes in the values from user input and then this||                                                                    $array[$y-1][$x] = $array[$y][$x];
    $array[$y][$x] = 0; || makes the movement

Comment: No, the code I gave is just for checking a position and performing the move. It is up to you how you collect the user input, that's a different question.

Comment: so i would start with $array[$y][$x]

Answer (score 1):

I guess first you should fill with 1 and 2 the cells corresponding to each type of tile. Then you can assign numbers 3 and 4 to the ones that are coronated.

1.You can ask each player for example staring x,y and ending x,y

Then for doing a movment you first need to check it is allowed. Obviously starting $array[$x][$y] for player 1 should contain a 1. Then You need to make rules for this, For example if you are player 1 you can only go from  $array[$x][$y] to $array[$x-1][$x-1], $array[$x-1][$y*1], etc when the place you wanna go is empty (filled with 0) Then you can check if more complicated moves are allowed like eating other player tile (which requires for example if you are player 1 to check things like $array[$x-2][$y-2] equals 0 and $array[$x-1][$y-1] equals 2. Then there is a series of more complicated verifications for the coronated ones that you should write. (besides always remember that you are moving within the limits of the array dimensions).

Finally you should alter the array cells that should be modified with the corresponding new values.

Comment: this is what i will do after i get movement I plan to write pseudo code after this part is done