# Assigning values to a multi-dimensional array for checkers

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

My question is instead of using coordinates to move can i assign numbers and letters so i can move with those values

Edit: I am outputting the board to html 8x8 table

```
$square = array( //    A B C D E F G H     
               0 array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
               1 array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
               2 array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
               3 array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
               4 array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
               5 array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
               6 array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
               7 array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
);
```

so when the user inputs : From: F1 to: G2 the pieces move

wouldn't it be better is i do this

```
Array ( 'A' => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 ) 
        'B' => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 ) 
        'C' => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 ) 
        'D' => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 ) 
        'E' => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 ) 
        'F' => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 ) 
        'G' => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 ) 
        'H' => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 ) 

    );
```

parseSquareFrom

```
function parseSquareFrom() {
    if (strlen($square) != 2) {
    return FALSE;
    }

    $coords = array(ord('A') - ord($square[0]),
            $square[1] - 1);


    // Perform bounds-checking.
    if ($coords[0] < 0 || $coords[0] > 7 || $coords[1] < 0 || $coords[1] > 7) {
    return FALSE;
    }

    return $coords;
}
$coords = parseSquare($square);
if ($coords === FALSE) {
    // Invalid input, handle this case.
} else {
    $piece = $board[$coords[0]][$coords[1]]; // for example
}
```

and parseSquareTo

```
function parseSquareTo() {
    if (strlen($square1) != 2) {
    return FALSE;
    }

  $coords1 = array(ord('A') - ord($square1[0]),
            $square1[1] - 1);


    // Perform bounds-checking.
    if ($coords1[0] < 0 || $coords1[0] > 7 || $coords1[1] < 0 || $coords1[1] > 7) {
    return FALSE;
    }

    return $coords1;
}

$coords1 = parseSquare($square);
if ($coords1 === FALSE) {
    // Invalid input, handle this case.
} else {
    $piece = $board[$coords1[0]][$coords1[1]]; // for example
}
```

can i use that with this code

```
    $board[$coords1[0]-1][$coords1[1]+1] = $board[$coords[0]][$coords[1]];
    $board[$coords[0]][$coords[1]] = 0;

    //eating action
    $board[$coords1[0]][$coords1[1]] = 0;
    $board[$coords1[0]-2][$coords1[1]+2] = $board[$coords[0]][$coords[1]];

    //if player is 'up' then the value of $way is 1 so
      $board[$x+(-1*$way)][$y+(1*$way)] = $board[$coords[0]][$coords[1]]; // position 2,2 becomes 1,3
   //if player is not 'up' then the value of $way is -1 so
      $board[$x+(-1*$way)][$y+(1*$way)] = $board[$coords[0]][$coords[1]]; // position 2,2 becomes 3,1
```

or is the $piece = $board[$coords1[0]][$coords1[1]]; cannot be used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: Parse the input string into an X,Y pair.  For example:

```
function parseSquare($square) {
    if (strlen($square) != 2) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $coords = array(ord('A') - ord($square[0]),
                    $square[1] - 1);

    // Perform bounds-checking.
    if ($coords[0] < 0 || $coords[0] > 7 || $coords[1] < 0 || $coords[1] > 7) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return $coords;
}
```

So given a square string like `$square = "F5";`

```
$coords = parseSquare($square);
if ($coords === FALSE) {
    // Invalid input, handle this case.
} else {
    $piece = $board[$coords[0]][$coords[1]]; // for example
}
```

Comment: The array of pieces that represents the board?

Comment: I edited the array in my post is that how it is or do i need to do a loop for the array before using the code you posted because i already have it in a loop to create the html table 8x8 board

Comment: No loops, just make sure you update the variables so they don't conflict.  So use `$square` instead of `$board` and store the user-input square in something other than `$square`.

Comment: $piece = $board[$coords[0]][$coords[1]]; // for example
change it to $piece = $square[$coords[0]][$coords[1]]; // for example

Comment: Right, exactly.  Just map the variables to new names like that.

Comment: do i also use that to update when i move a piece update the square that the piece move to and when i jump a piece remove the piece and update the square square the piece was in to a blank square

Comment: How you use the `$square` array is up to you.  You asked how to access a piece when the user entered an identifier like "F5" and I answered that.  This is beyond the scope of your original question.

Comment: can I still make an HTML table without the loop

Comment: You said **nothing** about outputting the board in HTML.  We were talking about parsing user-entered square coordinates, not displaying the board.

Comment: yea sorry for not clarifying that it was a mistake do i use your code after or before out putting the board into the loop for the html table

Comment: You use it whenever you need to resolve coordinates entered by the user into proper coordinates into the `$square` array.

Comment: so the user input something like f5 then the function process it

Comment: Correct.  The function maps user-supplied coordinates into an X/Y pair you can use to index the `$square` array.

Comment: so i use this with a different algorithm to handle movement

Comment: like the one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179722/movement-inside-an-multi-dimensional-array

Comment: so besides using this code ill have to make an algorithm that takes the processed f5 user input in your code makes the necessary move relating to the input then update the change in the board(array)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179722/movement-inside-an-multi-dimensional-array can you take a look at the code here an see if combining the code there will help

Comment: do i keep $quare - > function parseSquare($square)

Comment: Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in checkers.php on line 94

Comment: Then you passed in an array, not a string.

Comment: do i pass the array or convert the array into string then pass it through your code

Comment: For the thousandth time, you pass in the string that the user entered.  Not the board.  Not a piece.

Comment: It should be returning `array(4,4)`.  (The code you were using would have returned `array(4,5)` -- I've just updated my code, please grab a fresh copy of the function.)

Comment: You didn't update your code with my new function.  Those should return (0,1) and (1,2) respectively.

Comment: can i make the function process the input from both input forms: From and to

Comment: Yes, just pass each square to the function, one at a time.  (In other words, call the function twice, once for each input.)

Comment: function parseSquare($square) <--- From  To ---> function parseSquare($square2)

Comment: or function parseSquare($square, $Square2);

Comment: if i have to take both inputs from to then i will have to use two of this $piece = $board[$coords[0]][$coords[1]]; with check the position the piece is at --<FROM>--$board[$y][$x]  then move --<TO>--$board[$y-1][$x] = $board[$y][$x]; $array[$y][$x] = 0;

Comment: $piece = $board[$coords[0]-1][$coords[1]+1]; --> $board[$coords[0]-1][$coords[1]] = $board[$coords[0]][$coords[1]]; $array[$coords[1]][$coords[0]] = 0; can i try this

Comment: I have to functions using the code about function parseSquareFrom and parseSquareTo now for this part i have two of this $piece = $board[$coords[0]][$coords[1]] corresponding to each function  parseSquareFrom returns $coords and parseSquareTo returns $coords1 how will this affect the movement I have updated the code up in my question

Comment: a question about the bounds checking why not && instead of || because with || even if one is correct and all of them are wrong won't it execute

Comment: Because all of them must be true if the coordinates are in-bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that. You will just need to make sure that you are able to move to that area with some algorithm and make sure to change values when moving them around.

@ your recent comment:
If you take a look at this article there is a section for multidimensional arrays that is pretty helpful for a reference. This should help you. Let me know if this solves your issue.

[The Article Link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/PHP_Arrays)

Comment: how would i go about changing the values when i move them i know there are some array functions